# How to use onClick event with <Link> in reactjs

Tags: javascript, reactjs

i am trying to get the Id of a student by clicking on the . But it's giving me error like TypeError: Cannot read property 'handleClick' of undefined. What's wrong in here.?? First atleast i need to get this handleClick function to be working.

This is my react code:

```
class Premontessori extends React.Component{
      constructor(props){
        super(props);
        this.state={
          post:[],
          id:[]

        };
        this.handleClick = this.handleClick.bind(this);

      }

      handleClick(event) {
          alert(event);
        }


    componentDidMount(){
       let self = this;
      axios.get('http://localhost:8080/list')
      .then(function(data) {
          //console.log(data);
          self.setState({post:data.data});
          self.setState({id:data.data})
          });
      }


      render(){
        console.log(this.state.id);
        return(
          <div className="w3-container">
          <div className="w3-display-container">
        <div className="w3-panel w3-border w3-yellow  w3-padding-4 w3-xxlarge  ">
        <p >List Of Students</p>
         <div className="w3-display-right w3-container">
         <Link className="w3-btn-floating w3-yellow" style={{textDecoration:'none',float:'right'}} to="/createstudent">+</Link>

         </div></div>
         </div>


          <ul  className="w3-ul w3-card-4  w3-yellow">  {this.state.post.map(function(item, index) {

                           return (

                                <Link  to="/displaylist" style={{textDecoration:'none'}} key={index}  onClick={this.handleClick}>
                                <li className=" w3-hover-green w3-padding-16" >
                                <img src={require('./3.jpg')} className="w3-left w3-circle w3-margin-right " width="60px" height="auto" />
                                <span>{item.Firstname}</span><br/><br/>
                                </li>
                                 </Link>




    )}
    )}
    </ul>



    </div>
        );
      }
    }
    export default Premontessori;
```

Comment: try `onClick={this.handleClick.bind(this)}`

Answer (score 2):

When you pass `this.handleClick` to Link, at the moment the event happens and function gets executed, the latter happens in context of instance of Link. And since Link component doesn't have `handleClick` prop, the operation fails.

Try to declare `handleClick` in a way it gets bound to current component at the time of instantiation:

```
handleClick = event => {
  alert(event);
}
```

Or use `Function#bind` in your `render` function:

```
<Link onClick={this.handleClick.bind(this)} />
```

Answer (score 1):

- `Link` is already has an internal hanlder for clicking which is  redirection to another Route  , and it is a markup solution .
- React router provides also a non-markup solution to redirect which is `browserHistory.push`.

Thus :

```
   import {browserHistory} from 'react-router'

   handleClick(event) {
     event.preventDefault();
     alert('you clicked me');
     browserHistory.push('/displaylist');
   }

    <a  style={{textDecoration:'none'}} key={index}  onClick={this.handleClick}></a>
```

Instead of

```
   import {Link} from 'react-router'

   <Link  to="/displaylist" style={{textDecoration:'none'}} key={index}  onClick={this.handleClick}>
```

Comment: So you mean i can't directly use onclick with Link??

Comment: yes .. use the logic of `<Link />` which is `browserHistory.push` , NOT `<Link />`itself

Comment: But using arrow function for mapping i am able to work with onclick event. Doing like this is a right thing?